# Reading sequential data from TFRecords files within the TensorFlow graph?

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, sequential

I'm working with video data, but I believe this question should apply to any sequential data. I want to pass my RNN 10 sequential examples (video frames) from a TFRecords file. When I first start reading the file, I need to grab 10 examples, and use this to create a sequence-example which is then pushed onto the queue for the RNN to take when it's ready. However, now that I have the 10 frames, next time I read from the TFRecords file, I only need to take 1 example and just shift the other 9 over. But when I hit the end of the first TFRecords file, I need to restart the process on the second TFRecords file. It's my understanding that the `cond` op will process the ops required under each condition even if that condition is not the one that is to be used. This would be a problem when using a condition to check whether to read 10 examples or only 1. Is there anyway to resolve this problem to still have the desired result outlined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the recently added [`Dataset.window()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.12/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window) transformation in TensorFlow 1.12 to do this:

```
filenames = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(...)

# Define a function that will be applied to each filename, and return the sequences in that
# file.
def get_examples_from_file(filename):
  # Read and parse the examples from the file using the appropriate logic.
  examples = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(...)

  # Selects a sliding window of 10 examples, shifting along 1 example at a time.
  sequences = examples.window(size=10, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)

  # Each element of `sequences` is a nested dataset containing 10 consecutive examples.
  # Use `Dataset.batch()` and get the resulting tensor to convert it to a tensor value
  # (or values, if there are multiple features in an example).
  return sequences.map(
      lambda d: tf.data.experimental.get_single_element(d.batch(10)))

# Alternatively, you can use `filenames.interleave()` to mix together sequences from
# different files.
sequences = filenames.flat_map(get_examples_from_file)
```

Comment: map function on sequences is not working, I get map function not implemented on nested dataset error. @golmschenk Did this solution work for you? If yes, could you kindly post your solution snippet?